# Lerp color based on distance between 2 objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to know how to make a smooth color lerp based on distance between 2 objects. The color should lerp from green to red to green to red... Cube far = color red, cube near = color green.

I already got everything working, but the only thinks that isn't working is the fact that the color doesn't lerp smooth. This is how it looks like at the moment.
https://i.gyazo.com/a85852e76d2418ab7d44c18e152647c0.mp4

I am using this script for the color change:

```
    FindClosestCube ();
    float lerpProgress = 0f;
    GameObject cubeChildTop = null;
    GameObject closestCube = FindClosestCube (); 
    cubeChildTop = closestCube.transform.Find("Top").gameObject;

    if (cubeDiffX >= 0.8f || cubeDiffX <= -0.8f) 
    {
        lerpProgress = 0.5f;
    }
    if (cubeDiffX <= 0.8f || cubeDiffX <= -0.8f) 
    {
        lerpProgress = 1f;
    }
    if (cubeDiffX >= 1.6f || cubeDiffX <= -1.6f) 
    {
        lerpProgress = 0f;
    }
    if(closestCube != GameObject.Find("Cube (1)2"))
    {
        cubeChildTop.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.Lerp(redColor, greenColor, lerpProgress);
    }
```

So... how do I make it lerping smooth from red to green?

Comment: Cool looking game BTW

Comment: @K Scandrett, thanks a lot! Each level will have his own theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really easy.

**1**.Find the max distance that you think both of those Objects can travel apart.

The first thing you need to do is determine the max distance value those two GameObjects will be apart from. You need to pass that value into the `inValueMax` parameter of the  `mapValue` function fro **#2**.

You can determine that max value with this code:

```
public GameObject obj1;
public GameObject obj2;

void Update()
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(getSqrDistance(obj1.transform.position, obj2.transform.position));
}

public float getSqrDistance(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2)
{
    return (v1 - v2).sqrMagnitude;
}
```

Run it, manually move each Object/Cube then get the highest value both Objects can travel from each other with the `Debug.Log` message.

Looking that the video you posted I estimated that the distance value of `200` is fine for that but you still have to do your experiment with the script above if you want a perfect result.

**2**.Use the  [`map`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/map) to convert `0` and that `MAX_DISTANCE` distance range to `0f` and `1f` range

```
float mapValue(float mainValue, float inValueMin, float inValueMax, float outValueMin, float outValueMax)
{
    return (mainValue - inValueMin) * (outValueMax - outValueMin) / (inValueMax - inValueMin) + outValueMin;
}
```

It scales values between some certain point to another.

For example, you need to use the `Lerp` function to do this and the Lerp function takes `0` to `1` values. The `mapValue` function can scale any number to range between `0` and `1` that the `Lerp` function need.

For me, I will scale `0` to `200` range values to `0f` and `1f` range with the `mapValue` function.

**3**.Finally, use `Color.Lerp(near, far, lerp);` to lerp between Colors. The lerp value is the result value from **#2**.

---

**In Code**:

Once you find **#1**, plug that value to the `MAX_DISTANCE` variable from the script below should work:

```
public GameObject obj1;
public GameObject obj2;

Color near = Color.green;
Color far = Color.red;
const float MAX_DISTANCE = 200;

void Update()
{

    //Get distance between those two Objects
    float distanceApart = getSqrDistance(obj1.transform.position, obj2.transform.position);
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(getSqrDistance(obj1.transform.position, obj2.transform.position));

    //Convert 0 and 200 distance range to 0f and 1f range
    float lerp = mapValue(distanceApart, 0, MAX_DISTANCE, 0f, 1f);

    //Lerp Color between near and far color
    Color lerpColor = Color.Lerp(near, far, lerp);
    obj1.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = lerpColor;
}

public float getSqrDistance(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2)
{
    return (v1 - v2).sqrMagnitude;
}

float mapValue(float mainValue, float inValueMin, float inValueMax, float outValueMin, float outValueMax)
{
    return (mainValue - inValueMin) * (outValueMax - outValueMin) / (inValueMax - inValueMin) + outValueMin;
}
```

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for putting so much effort in it! It works perfectly! btw. what programm do you use for the gif?

Comment: Nice. I use LICEcap to capture screen.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are confused with the concept of lerp. When you apply `lerp`, `lerpProgress` should be continous values in [0, 1] to make it change smoothly. In your caes, you are setting them to 0, 0.5, 1.0, and that's where the colour is not appearing smoothly.

Remember that lerp (linear interpolation) is summing up two values with each having different contribution ratio. So if you have `Color A` and `Color B` that you want to lerp, you are saying that I want 40% from A and 60% from B and mix them up.

How much contribution ratio each instance should have is entirely up to you, and it is where you are designing your game to be.

One way I could think of is in terms of distance. If `Z` is moving between `X` and `Y`, then there are two distance ratios of `XZ` and `YZ`. If `Z` is 40% (0.4f) toward `X` and 60% (0.6f) toward `Z`, you could take 40% of `X`'s colour value and 60% of `Y`'s colour value, for example.

The idea is not limited to only 2 objects, but can be extended to N objects.

Edit:

Here's an example on how you could get a ratio from only X values. In this example I am assuming two predefined values of minX and maxX.

The idea is to consider the leftX to be the starting point. If x == left.x, it returns 0, and if x == right.x, it returns 1.

```
float GetDistanceRatio()
{
    float maxDistance = maxX - minX;
    float distanceFromLeft = currX - minX;
    float distanceFromLeftRatio = distanceFromLeft / maxDistance;

    return distanceFromLeftRatio;
}
```

Comment: I can understand a bit what you mean, but I don't understand how I would do that in my script? btw. only the "x" is translating.

Comment: Please check the code snippet from the editted answer. That is an typical example of how one would calculate lerp. If you are looking for a more specific answer let me know how you would want to achieve it.