# Lerp alpha based on distance between 2 objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to increase an image alpha channel based on the fact that an object is getting closer and closer to the player. I am using `Vector3.Distance()`
to get the distance from the player to the object but I don't know how should I convert the distance so that the value of `color.a` will get bigger and bigger as the distance get's smaller and smaller. 
Please point me in the right direction;

How can I make a number bigger based on the fact that another number is getting smaller?

Comment: You are asking for a lot - basically you need to determine what the maximum range is, get the current distance, and if less than the maximum range, change `color.a` accordingly. FYI, StackOverFlow is intended for specific questions after you have already tried to code something - why don't you try to put something together based on my comment. If that doesn't work, then you can update your question with the code you are trying to use to be more specific - and you may get some good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420414/3785314) post that explains how to lerp a color based on distance between two GameObjects. The only difference is that you want to lerp the alpha instead so everything written on that post should still be relevant to this. Just few modifications need to be made.

You just need to use  `Mathf.Lerp` instead of `Color.Lerp`. Also, you need to enable fade mode on the material. You can do that from the Editor or script. The code below is a modified code from the linked answer that should accomplish what you are doing. It also enables fade mode from code in the `Start` function.

```
public GameObject obj1;
public GameObject obj2;

const float MAX_DISTANCE = 200;

Renderer mRenderer;

void Start()
{
    mRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();

    //ENABLE FADE Mode on the material if not done already
    mRenderer.material.SetFloat("_Mode", 2);
    mRenderer.material.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.SrcAlpha);
    mRenderer.material.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
    mRenderer.material.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);
    mRenderer.material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
    mRenderer.material.EnableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
    mRenderer.material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
    mRenderer.material.renderQueue = 3000;
}


void Update()
{
    //Get distance between those two Objects
    float distanceApart = getSqrDistance(obj1.transform.position, obj2.transform.position);
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(getSqrDistance(obj1.transform.position, obj2.transform.position));

    //Convert 0 and 200 distance range to 0f and 1f range
    float lerp = mapValue(distanceApart, 0, MAX_DISTANCE, 0f, 1f);

    //Lerp Alpha between near and far color
    Color lerpColor = mRenderer.material.color;
    lerpColor.a = Mathf.Lerp(1, 0, lerp);

    mRenderer.material.color = lerpColor;
}

public float getSqrDistance(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2)
{
    return (v1 - v2).sqrMagnitude;
}

float mapValue(float mainValue, float inValueMin, float inValueMax, float outValueMin, float outValueMax)
{
    return (mainValue - inValueMin) * (outValueMax - outValueMin) / (inValueMax - inValueMin) + outValueMin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you want the effect to look, but it's basically a math question.

Something like:

```
color.a = 1.0 / distance
```

should get you started. Basically, the further from 1 `distance` gets (increasing), the closer to 0 `color.a` gets (decreasing). The opposite is thus true if `distance` decreases (`color.a` then increases).

You have to deal with values for `distance` getting inferior to 1 (if applicable), as it won't increase `color.a` anymore.

You also have to deal with `color.a` max possible value: is it 1.0 or 255 (or something else)? Replace the `1.0` in the formula with this max value. You may have to multiply `distance` by an arbitrary value so the effect isn't too fast or too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a function (in the mathematical sense) f(x) that maps an input (distance) value in the domain [0, infinity) to the output (alpha) range [1, 0]. One simple such function is [1/(1+x)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3iqdksxv3m) (click the link to see an interactive graph).

You can use the interactive graph and online math resources to play with the equation to find one that looks good to you. Once you have that figured out, implementing it in code should be easy!