# Lerp Text alpha based on distance between 2 objects

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, colors, alpha

for a project I need to modify the alpha value of a UI Text in Unity depending on the distance the player / viewer is from it. If he is closer than "visibleDistance", it should be completely visible / have an alpha value of 1.

The distance gets passed from OnTriggerStay(Collider other) in the viewer's behaviour to this function on the Text's Game Object:

```
public void UpdateTransparency(float maxDistance, float distance){
    maxDistance -= visibleDistance;
    float tmp = maxDistance/distance;
    tmp = 1/tmp;
    text.color = Color.Lerp(text.color, Color.clear, tmp);
}
```

If I print out tmp, it gives "correct looking" values, but nothing is happening to the text's color (text is correctly assigned in the Start function). The text is rendered on a World Space canvas.

Would be great if someone could help me with that :) Thanks in advance!

---

Update: Fixed it with a modified solution below:

```
public void UpdateTransparency (Vector3 viewerPos, float maxDistance){
    float distanceApart = Vector3.Distance(viewerPos, this.transform.position));
    float lerp = mapValue(distanceApart, maxDistance-3f, maxDistance, 0f, 1f);
    Color lerpColor = text.color;
    lerpColor.a = Mathf.Lerp(1, 0, lerp);
    text.color = lerpColor;
}


float mapValue(float mainValue, float inValueMin, float inValueMax, float outValueMin, float outValueMax)
{
    return (mainValue - inValueMin) * (outValueMax - outValueMin) / (inValueMax - inValueMin) + outValueMin;
}
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What do "correct looking" values look to you? 'tmp' should be in the range of 0 - 1.

Comment: It's above 1 when you get closer than visibleDistance, which shouldn't be a problem, right? If you are between maxDistance and visible Distance, the values are between 0 and 1, but the color doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to lerp the alpha of a GameObject, lerp the alpha, not the Color. This means should use use `Mathf.Lerp` instead of `Color.Lerp`. The `Mathf.Lerp` value should be assigned to `text.color.a` property and you should pass `0` and `1` to it.

Assusming that your `tmp` variable is good and returns values between 0 and 1, the code below:

```
float tmp = maxDistance/distance;
tmp = 1/tmp;
text.color = Color.Lerp(text.color, Color.clear, tmp);
```

should be replaced with something like this:

```
float tmp = maxDistance/distance;
tmp = 1/tmp;
Color lerpColor = text.color;
lerpColor.a = Mathf.Lerp(1, 0, tmp);
text.color = lerpColor;
```

If there are still issues with your code then there is a similar question for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47140071/lerp-alpha-based-on-distance-between-2-objects) but it is for a `MeshRenderer`. I modified that code to work with `Text` component. See below.

```
public GameObject obj1;
public GameObject obj2;

const float MAX_DISTANCE = 200;

Text text;

void Start()
{
    text = GameObject.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
}


void Update()
{
    //Get distance between those two Objects
    float distanceApart = getSqrDistance(obj1.transform.position, obj2.transform.position);
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(getSqrDistance(obj1.transform.position, obj2.transform.position));

    //Convert 0 and 200 distance range to 0f and 1f range
    float lerp = mapValue(distanceApart, 0, MAX_DISTANCE, 0f, 1f);

    //Get old color
    Color lerpColor = text.color;

    //Lerp Alpha between 1 and 0
    lerpColor.a = Mathf.Lerp(1, 0, lerp);

    //Apply modified alpha
    text.color = lerpColor;
}

public float getSqrDistance(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2)
{
    return (v1 - v2).sqrMagnitude;
}

float mapValue(float mainValue, float inValueMin, float inValueMax, float outValueMin, float outValueMax)
{
    return (mainValue - inValueMin) * (outValueMax - outValueMin) / (inValueMax - inValueMin) + outValueMin;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed answer. I now give the viewer's position to the UpdateTransparency function with your code within. When I print out _lerp_ I don't get values between 0 and 1, but much higher values.

I fixed it by using Vector3.Distance(...) and modified the minimum distance to my values so it doesn't show up last minute. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good. Your lerp value should be between 0 and 1 otherwise you will get unexpected result. Glad you got it working